# Treeview is not inserting or showing data

Tags: c#, mono, treeview, gtk#

I am using MonoDevelop to create a GUI but it doesn't contain a ListBox conrol. I read that Tree View is a good alternative so I'm trying to get it to work, but nothing appears to be added to the Tree View at all.

```
ListStore _store;

public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build ();

    _store = new Gtk.ListStore (typeof(string));
    lbErrors.Model = _store; // lbErrors is the Tree View

    Error("err");
}

public void Error(string err)
{
    var ii = _store.Append();
    _store.SetValues(ii, err);
}
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your table columns.

Try something like this:

```
var column = new TreeViewColumn ();
column.Title = "Column Name";
column.Clickable = false;

var renderer = new CellRendererText ();
column.PackStart (renderer, true);

column.AddAttribute (renderer, "text", 0);
lbErrors.AppendColumn (column);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it actually adds the items now but I don't want to use a column.. or at least make it invisible. Is this possible? I tried simply setting Visibility on the column to false but that hides all the data as well.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a property on the column, it's a property on the treeview: lbErrors.HeadersVisible = false;

Comment: Haven't been able to test the hiding of the header yet but I'm assuming that works, so thanks for your help ;D